# How to get the arity of a method?

Tags: objective-c, introspection

In Javascript, for example, you can get the arity (the number of arguments a function is supposed to take) by simply `func.length`. How can I get this information for a method in Objective-C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NSMethodSignature`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMethodSignature_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is awesome for all kind of reflection information.

```
SEL selector = @selector(foo:);
NSMethodSignature *sig = [someObj methodSignatureForSelector:selector]
int argCount = [sig numberOfArguments];
```

Answer (score 2):

When there’s no receiver object to send `-methodSignatureForSelector:` to, it’s possible to use `NSStringFromSelector()` and count the number of occurrences of the colon character.

Answer (score 1):

From The [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)

> **method_getNumberOfArguments**
>
> Returns the number of arguments accepted by a
> method.
>
> unsigned
> method_getNumberOfArguments(Method
> method) Parameters method A pointer to
> a Method data structure. Pass the
> method in question. Return Value An
> integer containing the number of
> arguments accepted by the given
> method.

Comment: NSMethodSignature will probably do the job more easily.