# How to determine whether a @selector wants a parameter?

Tags: objective-c, selector, introspection

The scenario presents itself where I have an object that stores an outside @selector for later use. By design, I would like to be able to add two kinds of selectors. The simple one, without parameters, like `[object add:@selector(doSomething)]`, and the more complex one, with one parameter, like `[object add:@selector(doSomething:)]` (mind the colon). Let's say the selector is stored in a variable `SEL mySelector`.

In the execution, I need to decide between `[anotherObject performSelector:mySelector]` or `[anotherObject performSelector:mySelector withObject:userInfo]]`.

The way I implemented this decision, is by providing a BOOL flag that redundantly stores whether the performance should be with or without the extra parameter. Yet although I can't find this in the docs, I have the feeling that I should also be able to ask the selector something like `-(BOOL)needsParameter`. I know, for example, that UIGestureRecognizer's addTarget:action: somehow makes this distinction automatically.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571739/how-to-get-the-arity-of-a-method

Comment: Very much a dupe! I've also learnt a new word today, it's `arity` :) thanks Yuras!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `NSMethodSignature` class for that. For instance,

```
SEL mySelector = …;

NSMethodSignature *msig = [anotherObject methodSignatureForSelector:mySelector];
if (msig != nil) {
    NSUInteger nargs = [msig numberOfArguments];
    if (nargs == 2) { // 0 non-hidden arguments
    }
    else if (nargs == 3) { // 1 non-hidden argument
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `NSStringFromSelector()` to get the string representation of `mySelector` and count the number of occurrences of the colon character.

Comment: Perfect! `NSMethodSignature` is indeed what I needed, and the example as you provided almost works right off the bet. `NSMethodSignature` will have at least two arguments, since `self` and the `@selector` occupy arguments 0 and 1. Change the example to `if (nargs == 2) { ... } else if (nargs == 3) { ... } else { ... }` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: No worries man, you helped me a great deal! Sometimes I wish I could extract this sort of thing from the docs myself, but I guess that is something that comes with experience...